# Rails Conditional Validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

So I have two models here:

```
class Screen < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  validates :screen_size, :numericality =>{:less_than_or_equal_to =>100,:greater_than_or_equal_to => 0},:if => "user.access==1"

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :screens
  attr_accessible :access
```

But this code doesn't work, cause no matter what value the user.access is, it will still execute the validation. What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you

Answer (score 21, accepted):

change:

```
:if => "user.access==1"
```

with:

```
:if => lambda { |screen| screen.user.try(:access) ==1 }
```

Because:

- you need to pass a function to evaluate condition on the fly
- if your screen doesn't have any user, a mere `screen.user.access` would throw an exception

Comment: I would go with the proc as well, but by [the docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#using-a-string-with-if-and-unless), it should accept a string to evaluate in the scope of the saved record.  I wonder if `self.user.try(:access) == 1` would work?

Answer (score 1):

You passed in a string to the :if executable proc/function parameter.  When this is a string, it tries to find a function with that name.  What you actually want is an anonymous function here using a lambda.

```
class Screen < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  validates :screen_size, :numericality => {:less_than_or_equal_to =>100, :greater_than_or_equal_to => 0}, :if => lambda {|s| s.user.access == 1 }
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :screens
  attr_accessible :access
end
```

Comment: According to [the docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#using-a-string-with-if-and-unless), this is untrue for Rails 3 (I can't remember if it was the case in 2).  A symbol would refer to a method, a string is evaluated in the scope of the record.