# how to skip model validation for particular function in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to skip some model validation for controller functions. I am doing like this

Model :

```
attr_accessible :skip_method_2
validates :name,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }, :unless => :skip_method_2
VALID_PHONE_REGEX = /\(?([0-9]{3})\)?([ .-]?)([0-9]{3})\2([0-9]{4})/
validates :phoneno, presence: true,uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false, :scope => :user_id}, format: { with: VALID_PHONE_REGEX }, :unless => :skip_method_2
```

Controller :

```
def contacts_callback
 @contacts = request.env['omnicontacts.contacts']   
 @contacts.each do |contact|
   next if current_user.contacts.exists?(:email => "#{contact[:email]}")
   contact1 = current_user.contacts.new(:skip_method_2 => true)
   contact1.name = contact[:name] 
   contact1.email = contact[:email]
   contact1.group = "Others"
   contact1.save
 end
  redirect_to "/contact"
end
```

I dont want to save it by :validation => false. I want to skip name and phoneno validation for contacts_callback function. But it is not working.

It gives error in controller -
undefined local variable or method `skip_method_2' for contacts_callback. I already mentioned attr_accessible in my model

Comment: you only declared skip_method_2 as attr_accessible. have you declared it in attr_accessor?

Comment: Yes i am using attr_writer also but it shows error in controller
undefined local variable or method `skip_method_2' for contacts_callback

Comment: no it should be attr_accessor because you need to write to it and you need to read it

Comment: I am using both attr_accessor and attr_writer but still it is not working

Comment: Does this answer your question? [skip certain validation method in Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881712/skip-certain-validation-method-in-model)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `validates :name,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }, :unless => :skip_method_2`

to

`validates :name,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }, :unless => lambda {|x|  x.skip_method_2}`

Also checkout [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7312088/1087546) answer

Comment: I try but it gives error - unknown attribute: skip_method_2 in my controller

Comment: You need to set both `attr_accessible :skip_method_2` and `attr_accssor :skip_method_2` before you do that