# Skip validates_presence_of from a belongs_to association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to skip validations of a belongs_to association if a criteria is true. Below is my code

```
class Venue < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events
  validates_presence_of :name, :postcode, :category
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :venue
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :venue
end
```

So what I need to do is skip the Venues `validates_presence_of` validation if a criteria from the Events model is true. So lets say if the `event_type` was equal to '1' then it will ignore the Venues `validates_presence_of` call but if `event_type` was '2' then it will still execute the `validates_presence_of` call.

Comment: If a Venue can have many events, what occurs if 1 event_type is of type 1 and another is of type 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I did something very similar to [this](http://www.tonyamoyal.com/2009/12/03/ruby-on-rails-skipping-validations-based-on-where-object-is-created/)

Answer (score 0):

There's a [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/41-conditional-validations) on this topic.  You can also check out [Rails Conditional Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7312073/rails-conditional-validation)

based on the link above, you'll have to pass a lambda such as:

```
:if => lambda { |venue| venue.event.try(:event_type) == 2 }
```

Comment: This assumes that a venue only has one event though. What if it has two as someone pointed out above?

Comment: can a validation validate more than one record at once?  i thought they're validated>saved one at a time.  that could be a bad assumption on my part...

Comment: Yes you can only validate one at a time, but I think the OP's logic is flawed. It doesn't really make sense to validate the parent model based on children in a has many relationship. There's probably a better way to do whatever he's trying to do.

Comment: A Venue can belong to many Events. I'm not sure how else to do this as a user just selects a Venue they wish to use for an Event they are creating. But sometimes an event won't have a venue hence the event_type. Also when creating an Event its a multistep form so the event doesn't get saved until the end and I believe the above won't work due to no primary / foreign keys, is this right?

Comment: If an Event may not have a Venue don't validate the presence of the venue_id. Then it should work since an associated Venue won't be assigned to the Event.

Comment: @AlthafHameez how do I not validate the presence of the venue_id if a Venue is not needed?