# Rails custom validation one after another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, custom-validators

I have a password field and that validates `presence` and `length` and both are working fine. But when I submit the form with blank password field, it displays error messages for both validations.

What I want is if the password is blank then `length` validator must not checked and display error message for only `presence` validator. Length validator will only be checked if password is present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Along with other validations pass this

```
:allow_blank => true
```

For example

```
validates :password, :presence => true, :length => { :maximum => 20, :allow_blank => true }
```

Comment: This allows blank entry.

Comment: `:allow_blank => true` should be inside the `length` clause: `:length => { :maximum => 20, :allow_blank => true }`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Object#with_options`](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/with_options) and [`ActiveRecord::Base#new_record?`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/new_record%3F):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  with_options :if => :new_record? do |user|
    user.validates :password, presence: true, length: { maximum: 20 }
  end
end
```

Look [rails conditional validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7312073/rails-conditional-validation).

Comment: Thanks for reply. How and where to use this `with_option`? Do I need to use it in model or in controller? Please explain a little more.

Comment: @Sambit validations always be in model.

Comment: I don't know how to use this. the above code gave me no result in validation. Do I need to add anything else in the code given by you?